# How can I  make more than one item as selected in play framework multi select

Tags: playframework

In multiple select if I give the value, its not getting as selected for all the values, Instead it selected only the first value. For Ex,

```
#{select 'roles', items:roleList, id:'roles',multiple:'multiple',
 value:params['roles']}
```

In this, if params['roles'] has two values only the first value getting selected. How to make two values as selected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the documentation for the [select tag](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.3/tags#select), it expects a single value in the value field. As such, I don't think the select tag will perform what you are looking for.

So, I would suggest a couple of things.

1. Raise a bug on Lighthouse, as this seems like a valid use case to be available
2. Use standard Groovy and HTML to output your own select tag. It should be fairly trivial to do this using the `#{list}` tag

Comment: @SelvakumarP: link for your bug?

Comment: @Janus https://play.lighthouseapp.com/projects/57987/tickets/1236-not-able-to-select-more-than-one-item-in-multi-select